# How do I make this block of code not always go to default, even though I give a character input?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, runtime-error

Yes, I have declared choice as a character variable in the same function, as well as `flag` as an integer. The `cout << flag` is for my reference, as to what's going wrong.

```
do
{
    cout << "\nWould you like to play again? Enter Y for yes, and N for no."<<endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
        {
            flag == 1;
            cout << flag;
        }
        case 'N':
        case 'n':   
        {       
            flag == 0;
            cout << flag;
        }
        default:
        {
            flag == 2;
            cout << "I did not understand that. Please enter a valid input!";   
            cout << flag;
        }
    }

}   while (flag == 2 );
```

The output after that is this:

> 00I did not understand that. Please enter a valid input!0

What's wrong?

Comment: Missing `break`s.

Comment: A good interactive debugger is your friend. If you were to run your code in a debugger and single-step through it line by line, you would immediately see what happened. If you tell us what OS you are using, I or someone could suggest a suitable debugger for you.

Comment: I suggest give at least some effort before posting anything.

Comment: Compiler warning options are your friend.  They should alert you to expressions such as `flag == 1;` that are unused and have no side effects, for a start.  And they may even be able to suggest inserting `break;` here and there.

Comment: If an answer suits you, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark below the answer's score ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you got a double typo:

1. You do not set `flag`, but only compare it to values (`==` instead of `=`)
2. You forgot a `break` statement.

So,

```
case 'Y': 
case 'y':   
{       
    flag == 1;
    cout << flag;
}
case 'N':   
case 'n': 
{       
    flag == 0;
    cout << flag;
}
default:
{
    flag == 2;
    cout << "I did not understand that. Please enter a valid input!";   
    cout << flag
}
```

should be

```
case 'Y':
case 'y':
    flag = 1;
    cout << flag;
    break;
case 'N': 
case 'n':        
    flag = 0;
    cout << flag;
    break;
default:
    flag = 2;
    cout << "I did not understand that. Please enter a valid input!";   
    cout << flag
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the [break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/switch-statement-cpp):

```
do
{
    cout << "\nWould you like to play again? Enter Y for yes, and N for no."<<endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            {
                flag == 1;
                cout << flag;
                break;
            }
        case 'N':
        case 'n':   
            {       
                flag == 0;
                cout << flag;
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                flag == 2;
                cout << "I did not understand that. Please enter a valid input!";   
                cout << flag
            }
    }

}   while (flag == 2 );
```

Comment: Damn, I'm embarrassed I didn't know that. Thanks a ton!